# sublime text- "list lines containing 'find' string

Tags: sublimetext2

How do I list the lines that contains the matches from the "find" command ? ie., I would like to list all the matching lines in a separate window. Currently one can only goto next / previous 'find'.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try 'Find in Files' (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on a Mac, presumably <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on a PC).

Search results will display in a new tab, and you can double-click any result to jump to that line in the matching file.

- To search only open files, put `<open files>` in the Where field.
- To show only the lines that matched without surrounding lines for context, toggle the 'Show Context' option (to the left of the 'Find All' panel).

Comment: That is what I was looking for, thanks. But Sublime also copies some lines to the Find Results buffer that does not match my search along with the lines that does, I think for context. Is there any settings that give me only the lines that match and none of the others lines? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ither yes, the 'Show Context' button on the left of the Find All panel (the icon is 3 horizontal lines) will toggle that setting.

Comment: works flawlessly

Answer (score 21):

1.Here is a reference: [How can I filter a file for lines containing a string in Sublime Text 2?](https://superuser.com/questions/452189/how-can-i-filter-a-file-for-lines-containing-a-string-in-sublime-text-2)

- Hit Ctrl+F(⌘+F) to "**Find All**" occurences;
- Hit Ctrl+L to **Expand** All Selection to Line.
- Then you can Ctrl+C(⌘+C) or Ctrl+Shift+K(⌃＋⇧＋K) to
  **copy/delete** the lines.

2.There's now a plugin for filtering lines: 
    https://github.com/davidpeckham/FilterLines 
It allows filtering and code folding based on strings or regular expressions.
[image: filterlines plugin：Edit->Line->Filter]

Comment: filter lines package is awesome!

Comment: works flawlessly

Answer (score 9):

I think the simplest way is just to search for the line like this -> **".*find_this_string.*"** and make sure that **regular expression** is ticked. Then you can click **"find all" (alt+enter)** and just copy and paste all results to a new window.